# Wrong answer in modular calculator

Tags: c++

I created a modular calculator meant to go through a series of math executions and at the end take the mod of everything before. However, I keep on getting the wrong result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num1, num2, ans = 0;
    char oper = ' ';
    cin >> num1>> oper >> num2;
    //The first time
    if (oper == '*')
        ans =num1*num2;
    else if (oper == '+')
        ans = num1+num2;
    //other times
    do {
        cin>> oper >> num2;
        if (oper == '*')
            ans =ans*num2;
        else if (oper == '+')
            ans = ans+num2;
    } while (oper!='%');
    if (oper == '%')
        ans = (ans % num2);
    cout<<ans;
}
```

Input:

```
4
* 8805
* 99
* 12
+ 6
+ 367
* 575
+ 66
+ 9
* 8
* 8
* 711
+ 130
* 5
+ 5
+ 1
+ 73
* 811
* 33
+ 56
+ 80
* 350
* 116
+ 179
* 383
* 12
+ 59
+ 5150
* 10
+ 5
+ 8783
* 48
* 84
* 7
+ 390
+ 7057
* 10
+ 8366
+ 8856
* 99
* 9
+ 3019
+ 228
* 334
+ 75
+ 6353
+ 7151
* 8
% 1408
```

Output: `-1240`
Expected: `808`

Any explanations? (`BigInt` or `double` or `unsigned int` instead of `int` don't seem to fix anything; I already tried all of those).

Comment: `BigInt` in C++? Could I see your implementation/library, please?

Comment: Can you generate a smaller example please? With such example, it is rather hard to debug.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, this is probably not how you were supposed to solve the problem. Maybe go for a way that actually makes use of the mathematical properties of modular arithmetic.

Comment: this is not homework; merely a programming problem. My implementation of bigint was included with "typedef unsigned long long bigint". A smaller example could perhaps be: "26 +3 *2 %3", although I haven't tested out my program with smaller values (I think overflow is my problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got wrong answer because of **int** overflow.

*Lets give you an example*

Lets say your input like below

```
4
* 432
* 422
* 432
% 8
```

your program will give wrong answer because

after first input, ans = 4 * 432 = 1728

after second input, ans = 1732 * 432 = 746496 (which is greater than *int*  highest range, it occurs int overflow and gives you wrong answer)

For this reason, we can use below modular arithmetic formula so that we can leave *int* overflow.

1. (A + B) % R = (A % R + B % R) % R
2. (A * B) % R = (A % R * B % R) % R

For Your Information,
(26+3*2)%3 = (26%3 + 3%3 * 2%3) % 3

**Try this**

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 100 // guess at most 100 lines input
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num1, count = 0, num2[MAX];
    char oper[MAX];
    cin >> num1;

    do{
       cin >> oper[count] >> num2[count];
       count = count + 1;
    }while(oper[count -1 ] != '%');

    int ans = num1, remainder = num2[count - 1]; // last number is remainder value

    for(int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
    {
       if(oper[i] == '+')
          ans = (ans % remainder + num2[i] % remainder) % remainder;
       if(oper[i] == '*')
         ans = (ans % remainder * num2[i] % remainder) % remainder;
    }

    cout << ans << endl;
 }
```

Comment: ah, thanks. I vaguely reading about that formula somewhere, but I couldn't recall it while doing my code. Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: I also noted that an alternate solution included pushing back a vector, which seems to have infinite size since the programmer who used it didn't take the mod of every number.

Comment: yes, you can use vector as it doesn't have limited storage location.